# How do I check for a specific ticker string inside my dataframe with a column name of Name and return if it is found in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to check if the input of 'ticker' is inside of this dataframe with 'Name' as the column name and if I do stock_final.query("Name == 'AMZN'"), it works. I am unsure what the value of ticker is because it is input from a user. I need to correct this my_tick function to return the ticker if it is in the dataframe, otherwise have an error message.

[image: Reference to problem]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
stock_final.query("Name == '{}'".format(ticker))
```

But if I understand correctly what you're really asking is whether a given ticker is in the column called "Name".  That can be done better like this:

```
(stock_final["Name"] == ticker).any()
```

Comment: I used the first one and it does work and returns the correct String of the Stock ticker, but I would like to have a truth if statement to see if Ticker is in the dataframe too which would return an error message if an invalid stock ticker is given in a function.

Comment: @MaxRoesler Then use my second line of code, which tells you only if the ticker exists in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

if the df.query() function does not find something in the column that macth, it will return a empty dataframe, in the begining is just a dataframe, but you can check if is empty by calling the df.empty property, for example

```
#some dataframe df
df.empty
```

This will return True if the dataframe is empty or False if it does not,

In your case, i recommend this

```
def my_tick(ticker):
    if not stock_final.query("Name == '{}'".format(ticker)).empty:
        return str(ticker)
```

Comment: Hi Evert, the '<ticker>' part does not work but you have the right idea of what I need. I want to check if the ticker is in the dataframe and continue if it is

Comment: @MaxRoesler Hi, just edit the answer. This maybe is more likely what you looking for